# Не работает navbar на мобильных устройствах bootstrap 5.3

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap, frontend

Добавил навигационную панель на сайт при помощи bootsrap, на компах все нормальное, а на планшет и мобильных устройствах (когда панель уменьшается в 3 полоски) она просто не работает. Когда юзер нажимает, она меняет цвет и все. Помоги пожалуйста

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #150437;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: yellow;">ITZ</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#" style="color: white;">Главная</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="link.html" style="color: white;">Ссылки</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true" style="color: grey;">Политика</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Ваш код работет на мобильных разрешениях. [Скриншот](https://imgur.com/gallery/C29AIEH)
- Убедитесь, добавили ли Вы

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

перед закрывающимся тегом `</body>`

- [Тут пример на CodePen](https://codepen.io/makhnanov/pen/GRPNRqz)
- Также убедитесь что на мобильном устройстве в браузере работает JavaScript
- Возможно другие Ваши скрипты могут мешать корректной работе NavBar